# java Tigase Perforamnce

Tags: java, performance, netty, tigase

Why Tigase Server can reach so many connections? http://www.tigase.org/content/tigase-load-tests-again-500k-user-connections

Could I reach 100,000 connections hypothetically with Netty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made Netty accepted 100k connection with Netty. 
In theory, a socket is identified by src_ip,src_port,dst_ip,dst_port,protocol.
Because port is in range (0-65k), **each client IP** is limited about 65k connections to server, so if you have two ip address(two clients host) you can easily reach such that number of concurrent connections.